# AWS CLI create ec2 instance UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to create a new EC2 instance with the AWS console tools using this command:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-9abea4fb --count 1 –-instance-type t2.micro --key-name my_key_name --security-group-ids my_rule --region us-west-2
```

But I keep getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 27, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 23, in main
    return awscli.clidriver.main()
  File "/Users/davesmith/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 56, in main
    return driver.main()
  File "/Users/davesmith/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 203, in main
    sys.stderr.write(str(e))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first `-` in your `--instance-type` parameter is some sort of unicode dash.  Fonts can obscure this, but it worked when I manually edited it to be a minus-sign instead.

Comment: Agree, looks like em-dash. This can happen automatically in some text editors when you type two dashes, it consolidates them into an em-dash.